# Conda install package error: missing zlib.dll

Tags: windows-7, python, anaconda

So I am quite a beginner when it comes to Python and Anaconda, but I have managed to install anaconda3. When I wanted to add some new package (`ftfy`), I tried to do it through the command line on Windows 7:

```
conda install ftfy
```

I have added the anaconda folder and `anaconda3/Scripts` to my PATH variable, however, when running the command I get an error saying:

> The progam can't start because zlib.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

How do I solve it (without reinstalling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `xxxx\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin` to your path.